# Generate Swagger JSON with FromForm attribute and Array Properties

Tags: asp.net, swagger

I am trying to generate swagger specification for my service and it is failing with this error.

```
Error: Swagger schema validation failed.
  Data does not match any schemas from 'oneOf' at #/paths//abc/{id}/createFile/post/parameters/3
    Data does not match any schemas from 'oneOf' at #/paths//abc/{id}/createFile/post/parameters/3
      Missing required property: schema at #/
      Data does not match any schemas from 'oneOf' at #/
        Additional properties not allowed: properties at #/items
        Additional properties not allowed: properties at #/items
        Additional properties not allowed: properties at #/items
        Missing required property: required at #/
    Missing required property: $ref at #/paths//abc/{id}/createFile/post/parameters/3
```

If I remove the `AdditionalInput` property from the `InputClass` then the Swagger spec generation is successful.
What should be done to fix this issue?

```
public class InputClass
{
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<CustomKVP> AdditionalInput { get; set; }
}

public class CustomKVP
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}


[HttpPost]
[Route("abc/{id}/createFile")]
[SwaggerOperation(OperationId = "createFile")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateFileAsync([FromRoute] string id, [FromForm] InputClass inputClass)
{
}
```

Also, if I change `FromForm` to `FromBody` then Swagger Spec is getting created.

Swagger JSON with input objects as `FromForm`

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "title": "Service - v1",
        "description": "Web API service.",
        "version": "v1"
    },
    "paths": {
        "/abc/{id}/createFile": {
            "post": {
                "tags": [
                    "createFile"
                ],
                "summary": "A create file operation",
                "operationId": "createFile",
                "consumes": [
                    "multipart/form-data"
                ],
                "produces": [
                    "application/json"
                ],
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "in": "path",
                        "name": "id",
                        "description": "Id",
                        "required": true,
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "in": "formData",
                        "name": "File",
                        "type": "file"
                    },
                    {
                        "in": "formData",
                        "name": "Name",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "in": "formData",
                        "name": "AdditionalInput",
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/CustomKVP"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Returns the output model.",
                        "schema": {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/OutputInfo"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "OutputInfo": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "uploadURL": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "CustomKVP": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "value": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error Experienced on Swagger UI.

```
Structural error at paths./abc/{id}/createFile.post.parameters.3.items
should NOT have additional properties
additionalProperty: $ref
```

Swagger JSON with input objects as `FromBody`

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "Service - v1",
    "description": "Web API service.",
    "version": "v1"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/abc/{id}/createFile": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "createFile"
        ],
        "summary": "A create file operation",
        "operationId": "createFile",
        "consumes": [
          "application/json-patch+json",
          "application/json",
          "text/json",
          "application/*+json"
        ],
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "path",
            "name": "id",
            "description": "Id",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "in": "body",
            "name": "inputClass",
            "description": "Input to create a file",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/InputClass"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Returns the output model.",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/OutputInfo"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "InputClass": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "file": {
          "format": "binary",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "additionalInput": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/CustomKVP"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "OutputInfo": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "uploadURL": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "CustomKVP": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "value": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to Github and read the OpenAPI-Specification schema. It is against this schema the swagger json is getting validated.

https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/schemas/v2.0/schema.json

I understood that `$ref` is not the property that `FormData` allows. It only allows Primitive datatypes.

It makes sense that the schema doesn't allow non-primitive datatypes as HTML forms doesn't have elements that can submit non-primitive datatypes.

I have changed the API specification. I now take the non-primitive datatype as a string and de-serialize it to an object in my server side code.